# Make statistic of bigrams

Tags: text-processing, tr

I have a text file, which has one word in each line and I would like to do bigrams and count repetitions (statistics) of each bigram.

My approach:

```
cat TEXTEN1.txt | tr '*\n' '*? *\n'
```

I would like to do two columns, but this solution fails.

Comment: *"do bigrams"* meaning what, exactly?

Comment: sample input and output would go a long way towards making this clearer

Comment: It's not clear on if you are looking for a letter-based bigrams (i.e. "ab","cd" ..), in which case it could be as simple as that `cat TEXTEN1.txt|grep -o ..|sort|uniq -c`, or "word - word" bigrams in which case you should specify on if you would like all the possible combinations of words or just combine two words on each two consecutive lines to make a bigram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste -d' ' - - < TEXTEN1.txt`

To get a count of the bigrams produced:

`paste -d' ' - - < TEXTEN1.txt | sort | uniq -c`

However, this method is going to exclude half the bigrams. For example, if your input file is:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
alpha
beta
gamma
```

The bigrams will include lines 1-2, lines 3-4, and lines 5-6 but not lines 2-3 and lines 3-4.

One way you could conceivably address this would be to create a copy of the input file and add a non-word to the top (e.g. '#') and then filter the result containing the non-word:

`cat <(paste -d' ' - - < TEXTEN1.txt; paste -d' ' - - < TEXTEN2.txt) | sort | uniq -c | grep -v #`

Answer (score 0):

If what you what is to combine words on each two consecutive lines to make a bigram, you can do it like that:

```
cat TEXTEN1.txt|sed 'N; s/\n/ /'|sort|uniq -c
```

this will combine the consecutive pairs of lines like that 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 e.t.c

If what you want is to combine every +1 line (i.e. 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 ...), you can do it like this

```
cat TEXTEN1.txt|sed -n ':a N;s/\n/ /p;s/\w* //;ta'|sort|uniq -c
```

or use (a somewhat more elegant) `sed + paste` [combination](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350594/182018) by @don_crissti

Comment: This won't print all digrams, it has the same problem as _cherdt_'s 1st paste solution... and btw, `cat` is definitely not needed when using `sed`

Comment: @don_crissti yep it will just  "combine words on each two consecutive lines", i.e. 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 e.t.c, as stated, I imply, based on the OP's code, that this is what he wants (that might not be true, so it would nice for OP to clarify that).

Comment: `cat is definitely not needed when using sed` really ? :)

Comment: well, OP's code doesn't make sense to me tbh - kudos to you if you could figure that out - I assumed digrams means _any two adjacent words/lines_ - that means pairing 2-3, 4-5 etc too - which shouldn't be a big deal for `sed` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

On `gnu` systems you could run:

```
paste <(head -n -1 infile) <(tail -n +2 infile) | sort | uniq -c
```

Portably:

```
sed -e '1!{$!p' -e '}' infile | paste -d' ' - -  | sort | uniq -c
```

or

```
awk 'NR>1{i=t" "$0; z[i]++};{t=$0}END{for (i in z){print z[i], i}}' infile
```